# How to run custom code as part of WiX burn MBA on install-complete and support rollback

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I need to embed, invoke and run some custom code as part of my custom managed bootstrapper application, as a post-install step. This custom code is within a class library that I have included as a reference in my MBA project. So, right after the state becomes `InstallationState.Applied` I plan on invoking this custom code. However, I am unable to figure out how I could tie in a failed state of this custom code to initiate the bootstrapper to rollback, since the progress callback would have been completed by now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per WiX & Burn's lead dev Rob Mensching [here, point-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571083/2055220), it seems any custom code that needs to facilitate rollback in the setup process should be run as a custom action, and not as part of the bootstrapper application, as I wanted to. I went ahead and did as Rob suggested, and everything works as expected. However, since the custom action runs significant code, I may in future put that in a WiX extension.